# How to filter query with a dummy column in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to set a where condition in my query based on a dummy column in my select statement.

```
select *,
       dbo.DictanceKM(cast(u.latitude as float),
       @lat,
       cast(u.longitude as float),@long) as distance 
from Table u
where distance < 10
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify it directly:

```
select *,dbo.DictanceKM(cast(u.latitude as float),
                        @lat,cast(u.longitude as float),@long) as distance 
from Table u
where dbo.DictanceKM(cast(u.latitude as float),
                     @lat,cast(u.longitude as float),@long)<10
```

or use subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select *,dbo.DictanceKM(cast(u.latitude as float),
                              @lat,cast(u.longitude as float),@long) as distance 
      from Table u) sub
WHERE distance < 10
```